# collection_select is not creating the association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to add a collection_select of ranches to my staff
And I saw that it's better to create an extra table to make this association. 
And I follow some tutorial, but is not working on my side

This is my code :

Staffs/_form :

```
<%= form_for(@staff) do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

    <%= fields_for(@staff_ranch) do |x| %>
    <div class="field">

      <%= x.collection_select(:ranch_id, @all_ranch, :id, :name, { }, {:multiple => true}) %>
    </div>
  <%end%>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My models :
- Ranch :

```
has_many :ranchstaffs
has_many :staffs, :through => :ranchstaffs
```

- Staff :

```
has_many :ranchstaffs
has_many :ranches, :through => :ranchstaffs
```

-Ranchstaff :

```
belongs_to :ranch
belongs_to :staff
```

Staff controller :

```
   class StaffsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_staff, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /ranches
  # GET /ranches.json
  def index
    @staffs = current_user.staffs
  end

  # GET /ranches/1
  # GET /ranches/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /ranches/new
  def new
    @staff = Staff.new
    @all_ranch = current_user.ranches
    @staff_ranch = @staff.ranchstaffs.build
  end

  # GET /ranches/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ranches
  # POST /ranches.json
  def create
    @staff = Staff.new(staff_params)

    @staff.update(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @staff.save
        format.html { redirect_to @staff, notice: 'Staff was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @staff }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @staff.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ranches/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ranches/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @staff.update(staff_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @staff, notice: 'Staff was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @staff }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @staff.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ranches/1
  # DELETE /ranches/1.json
  def destroy
    @staff.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to staffs_url, notice: 'Ranch was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_staff
      @staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def staff_params
      params.require(:staff).permit(:name, :user_id, :cat, :ranch_id)
    end
end
```

Can you explain me why the model ranchstaff was not created after a creation of a new staff ?

Comment: Where is your `create` method?. here you are just instantiating it.

Comment: Hi @Abhinay, thanks for your respond, I just add the create function. What do you mean by just analyzing  ?

Comment: If you are using rails 4+ then is the ranch_id permitted and in your `Staff` model are you accepting the nested attributes?

Comment: Hi @Deep, nope Just a simple model, no nested form and yep, I'm using rails4

Comment: Can you post your complete `form` and the `strong_params` method.

Comment: @Deep, Ok, I suppose that the strong params are the private params function ? I edit my post to inclue all of that

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `fields_for` you are using nested form but you are not permitting the parameters properly. First make change in your form:

```
<%= f.fields_for(@staff_ranch) do |x| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= x.collection_select(:ranch_id, @all_ranch, :id, :name, { }, {:multiple => true}) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then in your controller:

```
def staff_params
  params.require(:staff).permit(:name, :user_id, :cat, ranchstaff_attributes: [ranch_id: []])
end
```

And in your `Staff` model write:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ranchstaffs
```

Then your `ranchstaff` should be created when the `User` is being created.

Comment: Cool, thanks man, but the I actually want to create it when I create a new Staff, and it's to link the new staff to the actual ranchs of the users. You know how I can generate that ?

Comment: So this should do the same thing. While creating staff you will select a ranch and it will get associated to the staff.

Answer (score 0):

Your ranch_id is coming in an array. So u have to specify that ranch_id would be array in strong parameters.
so your staff_params method would look like this

```
def staff_params
  params.require(:staff).permit(:name, :user_id, :cat, :staff_ranch_attributes =>[:ranch_id => []])
end
```